# How can I show rectangle size on top left corner in C#

Tags: c#

[image]

How can I show rectangle size on top left corner in C#.

Done:

```
int Starting = this.endX - this.startX;
int Ending = this.endY - this.startY;
if(startY<15) {
   label1.Text = Starting.ToString() + " , " + Ending.ToString(); 
   label1.SetBounds(startX + 3, startY + 5, 20, 10);
} else {
   label1.Text = Starting.ToString() + " , " + Ending.ToString();
   label1.SetBounds(startX + 3, startY - 18, 20, 10);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by C#? C# can be used in console, web,windows, mobile applications...Please be more specific...

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? UWP? Xamarin? Unity? There are a bunch of GUI frameworks for C#? and each of them come with their own method of doing this. Please be more specific to what it is you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using label and defining starting positions

```
               int Starting = this.endX - this.startX;
               int Ending = this.endY - this.startY;

               if(startY<15)
               {
                   label1.Text = Starting.ToString() + " , " + Ending.ToString();
                   label1.SetBounds(startX + 3, startY + 5, 20, 10);
               }
               else 
               {
                   label1.Text = Starting.ToString() + " , " + Ending.ToString();
                   label1.SetBounds(startX + 3, startY - 18, 20, 10);
               }
```